# Lilypond, add stroke through stem

Tags: lilypond

I'm trying to typeset this music:

[image]

I can get close with this, but I would really like the stroke through the dotted-quarter in the tuplets.

```
\relative{                                                                      
  \clef bass                                                                    
  \key f \major                                                                 
  \numericTimeSignature                                                         
  \time 2/2                                                                     
  \tempo "Animato assai." % 2 = 110                                             
                                                                                
  \mark 7                                                                       
                                                                                
  a,,8\ff r8                                                                    
  a'8     r8                                                                    
  \tuplet 3/2 { a8[ a a ] }                                                     
  a8 r8 |                                                                       
                                                                                
  d,1-> |                                                                       
                                                                                
  %            V~~~ Can I put a strike through this stem?                       
  \tuplet 3/2 {a'4.} a8 r8                                                      
  \tuplet 3/2 { a8 [ a8 a8 ] } a8 r8 |                                          
  %             ^~~~  Or can I collapse these?                                  
                                                                                
  d,1-> |
}
```

Which gives me:

[image]

I've tried setting the Flag.stroke-style, but that just puts a stroke through 8ths that already have flags.

```
\override Flag.stroke-style = #"grace"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try looking up `\repeat tremolo`. I'm not at my computer so I can't test it, sorry.

---

Update:

[Tremolo](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.25/Documentation/notation/tremolo-repeats) is the magic word that's missing here.  It actually has nothing to do with tuplets.

`\repeat tremolo x c'y` means:  Repeat `c'y` `x` times.  In this case, we want `\repeat tremolo 3 a'8` for three eights.

A short-hand form is `c'x:y` where `x` is the total duration and `y` is the length of a single note.  In this case:  `a'4.:8` will give us eights until a dotted-quarter has elapsed.

Here's the updated code:

```
\relative{                                                                      
  \clef bass                                                                    
  \key f \major                                                                 
  \numericTimeSignature                                                         
  \time 2/2                                                                     
  \tempo "Animato assai."                                             
                                                                                
  \mark 7                                                                       
                                                                                
  a,,8\ff r8                                                                    
  a'8     r8                                                                    
  \tuplet 3/2 { a8[ a a ] }                                                     
  a8 r8 |                                                                       
                                                                                
  d,1-> |                                                                       
                                                                                
  %            V~~~ Short-hand for "repeat tremolo 8ths until 4. has elapsed                       
  \tuplet 3/2 {a'4.:8} a8 r8                                                      
  \tuplet 3/2 {\tremolo repeat 3 a8 } a8 r8 |                                          
  %             ^~~~  Or "repeat 3 8ths in a tremolo"                               
                                                                                
  d,1-> |
}
```

That gives this:

[image]

Comment: Something worth noting is that while the "short-hand form" is quicker to type, and saves some mental arithmetic, it doesn't affect midi output.